# highcharts-export-server does not execute callback and returns error

Tags: highcharts

I have installed the Highcharts-export-server and I can create .png from the commandline.

But if I add a callback-parameter, chart generation succeeded but the callback function is not called and ennded up with an error.

**Commandline:**

```
highcharts-export-server -infile 'c:\temp\console.json' -outfile 'c:\temp\test.png' 
--type 'png' -callback 'c:\temp\callback.js'
```

**Callback.js:**

```
function(chart) {
chart.renderer.label('This label is added in the callback', 100, 100)
    .attr({
        fill : '#90ed7d',
        padding: 10,
        r: 10,
        zIndex: 10
    })
    .css({
        color: 'black',
        width: '100px'
    })
    .add();
  }
```

**Error:**

```
phantom worker 1 unexpected data - SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

undefined:1 in appendChild
:15
:16
{"filename":"c:\\temp\\test.png"}
```

Regards
Normen

Comment: I receive a similar error - it seems that is something with loading a file as a callback. I suggest to report the bug on github https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues

Comment: Thanks for testing it.
I have reported a bug on github.
https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/22